# Understanding array allocated size

Tags: go

In a Go program I allocate a big array (not a slice):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var BigArray [10 * 1024 * 1024]byte //10MB

func main() {
    fmt.Println(len(BigArray), BigArray[100])
}
```

When I observe the program's memory footprint, this is not apparent. In fact, no matter how large the array size is.
Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Maybe you don't use the `BigArray` variable and the compiler removes it completely. Also how are you checking used / allocated memory? 1 MB isn't particularly big, try something bigger. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @icza I do use it (just print its length which is correct or access one of its members which is zeroed). 
I also tried with bigger sizes, the footprint remains the same.
I used MacOS's Activity monitor, and also `ps -o rss,vsz`

Comment: Why was the question closed? what needs to be clarified?

Comment: You might also try to read up on how contemporary commodity operating systems manage memory on (again, contemporary commodity) hardware. Basically, a request for some memory may be satisfied by purely allocating (another) chunk in the virtual address space of the running process; no memory is _physically_ assigned to that address range yet. To make it ascually assigned ("mapped") you have to somehow "touch" that memory—for insance, by writing a byte in each page-sized block of that array's memory (typically, a page is 4k but YMMV),—this will force allocating physical memory pages.

Comment: "what needs to be clarified?" -- As mentioned in the first comment: "Please show a minimal reproducible example."

Comment: «Why was the question closed?» Basically because it's not about _programming_ in Go—please read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Peoperly answering it required several back-and-forths for narrowing down the problem (if any), and even after that it's still hardly answerable. Basically, if we were sitting next to each other, I could lecture you on these memory issues, and it would took, like, half an hour. That's not suitable for SO format, you know ;-)

Comment: @Flimzy this is the example. I cannot exemplify how I manually check for memory footprint in another window. If you are suggesting that my initial understanding that this should have allocated the memory then it's also a good indicator for me

Comment: You might consider asking on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) or [`r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/)—they are fine for _conversations,_ and SO is not, sorry.

Comment: No, it's not a complete example. That line of code won't even compile alone (due to an unused variable). A complete, reproducible example is complete, and reproducible. Ideally, a `main.go` that you're testing. At minimum, a function that one could copy-paste into a `main.go`.

Comment: You may start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and follow the links. But actually a book like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Operating-Systems-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/013359162X) might have you covered on that more firmly.

Comment: That said, can you clarify how you are observing the memory used? The problem might be in the measurement.

Comment: @hasan here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236109/understanding-array-allocated-size#comment115330833_65236109

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely seeing is [virtual memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) rather than any special behaviour on the part of Go.  If I compile your test program and inspect the binary with `size`, we can see that the array hasn't been optimised out, and is represented in the ["bss"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) section of the executable:

```
$ go build test.go
$ size test
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1363348   86448 10666480    12116276     b8e134 test
```

If we increase the size of the array, the bss size sees a similar increase.  This section represents zero initialised data in the program.  It doesn't affect the size of the executable on disk, since the only thing the OS needs to know is how much of it there is.

When you run the program, the OS reads the executable and loads it into memory so it can be run.  A naive implementation of the program loader would allocate the 10MB of memory for the bss data and initialise it to zero.  That's not quite what happens on a Linux system.

Instead, it will reserve 10 MB of address space with no backing store.  When the program tries to read or write to any memory in that address range, a page fault will be generated.  The kernel will respond by allocating a page, initialising it to zero, hook it up to the process's address space, and let the program continue executing.

As this test program only accesses a single item in the array, only a single 4KB page is allocated.  The benefit of this system is that the OS only ends up allocating memory that the program actually uses, allowing you to run more programs simultaneously than you otherwise might.  The downside is that any page fault could result in an out of memory situation, where the kernel will need to decide to kill one or more processes to continue on.